# How to create an instance of Windows Firewall interface object in Unity

Tags: unity, networking, windows, .net

I am trying to make the game add itself into the Firewall rule. I already referenced NetFwTypeLib.dll into the project. It led me to this line of code here:

```
INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(INetFwPolicy2)) as INetFwPolicy2;
```

This gave me an exception of:

```
MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type NetFwTypeLib.INetFwPolicy2
```

I already tried

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
```

which led me to another exception of:

```
NotImplementedException: Unmanaged activation is not supported
```

I don't know what to try anymore. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Adding a firewall rule requires administrator privs which his not something a game generally needs or should require. See [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/games-and-firewalls).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Our game requires a UDP communication with a mobile phone that the firewall automatically blocks. So, that's how it is.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn your tutorial on Direct3D push me through my internship btw. Thank you!